# Python/Tkinter -

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an application to calculate the billing tax, and at the same time, if the value of the calculation base ((receita1 * 32/100) + (receita2 * 8/100)) is greater than 60k, it calculates the surplus of that, (((receita1 * 32/100) + (receita2 * 8/100)) - 60000), however is giving the following error:

```
v_result3.set(real(receita1 * 32 / 100) + (receita2 * 8 / 100))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Here is the complete code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x350')

def real(my_value):
    a = '{:,.2f}'.format(float(my_value))
    b = a.replace(',', 'v')
    c = b.replace('.', ',')
    return c.replace('v', '.')

l_label = Label(root, text='Receita 1')
l_label.place(x=10, y=10)
e_entry = Entry(root)
e_entry.place(x=100, y=10)

l_label2 = Label(root, text='Receita 2')
l_label2.place(x=10, y=40)
e_entry2 = Entry(root)
e_entry2.place(x=100, y=40)

v_result = DoubleVar()
l_result = Label(root, textvariable=v_result)
l_result.place(x=10, y=70)
l_explic = Label(root, text='<-- receita1 x 32%')
l_explic.place(x=100, y=70)

v_result2 = DoubleVar()
l_result2 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result2)
l_result2.place(x=10, y=100)
l_explic2 = Label(root, text='<-- receita2 x 8%')
l_explic2.place(x=100, y=100)

v_result3 = DoubleVar()
l_result3 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result3)
l_result3.place(x=10, y=130)
l_explic3 = Label(root, text='<-- receita1 x 32% + receita2 x 8%')
l_explic3.place(x=100, y=130)

v_result4 = DoubleVar()
l_result4 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result4)
l_result4.place(x=10, y=160)
l_explic4 = Label(root, text='<-- result if')
l_explic4.place(x=100, y=160)


def calc():
    receita1 = int(e_entry.get())
    receita2 = int(e_entry2.get())

    v_result.set(real(receita1 * 32 / 100))
    v_result2.set(real(receita2 * 8 / 100))
    v_result3.set(real(receita1 * 32 / 100) + (receita2 * 8 / 100))

    if v_result3.get() > 60000:
        v_result4.set(real((receita1 * 32 / 100) + (receita2 * 8 / 100)) - 60000)
    elif v_result3.get() < 60000:
        v_result4.set(real(receita1 * 32 / 100) + (receita2 * 8 / 100))


    e_entry.delete(0, END)
    e_entry2.delete(0, END)


bt = Button(root, text='calc', command=calc)
bt.place(x=10, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Function `real` returns a string. Thus, `real(receita1 * 32 / 100)` is a string, and `(receita2 * 8 / 100)` is a float. Try `float(real(receita1 * 32 / 100)) + (receita2 * 8 / 100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this problem because you're mixing and matching numbers formatted as strings and numbers themselves.

It's better to form your computation into input / computation / output. I've also taken the liberty to use `Decimal` numbers instead of plain integers, since you seem to be dealing with money, and precision is generally tantamount in that domain.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("350x350")


l_label = Label(root, text="Receita 1")
l_label.place(x=10, y=10)
e_entry = Entry(root)
e_entry.place(x=100, y=10)

l_label2 = Label(root, text="Receita 2")
l_label2.place(x=10, y=40)
e_entry2 = Entry(root)
e_entry2.place(x=100, y=40)

v_result1 = StringVar()
l_result1 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result1)
l_result1.place(x=10, y=70)
l_explic1 = Label(root, text="<-- receita1 x 32%")
l_explic1.place(x=100, y=70)

v_result2 = StringVar()
l_result2 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result2)
l_result2.place(x=10, y=100)
l_explic2 = Label(root, text="<-- receita2 x 8%")
l_explic2.place(x=100, y=100)

v_result3 = StringVar()
l_result3 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result3)
l_result3.place(x=10, y=130)
l_explic3 = Label(root, text="<-- receita1 x 32% + receita2 x 8%")
l_explic3.place(x=100, y=130)

v_result4 = StringVar()
l_result4 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result4)
l_result4.place(x=10, y=160)
l_explic4 = Label(root, text="<-- result if")
l_explic4.place(x=100, y=160)


def real(my_value):
    return str(my_value.quantize(Decimal("0.02"))).replace(".", ",")


def calc():
    # Get inputs
    receita1 = Decimal(int(e_entry.get()))
    receita2 = Decimal(int(e_entry2.get()))
    # Compute
    result1 = receita1 * Decimal("0.32")
    result2 = receita2 * Decimal("0.08")
    result3 = receita1 + receita2
    if result3 > 60000:
        result4 = result3 - 60000
    else:
        result4 = result3

    # Output
    v_result1.set(real(result1))
    v_result2.set(real(result2))
    v_result3.set(real(result3))
    v_result4.set(real(result4))
    e_entry.delete(0, END)
    e_entry2.delete(0, END)


bt = Button(root, text="calc", command=calc)
bt.place(x=10, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```